# Sitecore 8: MVC or Web Forms?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sitecore, sitecore8

I am new to Sitecore but I need to develop a all new Sitecore project. 
Although I have some experience with ASP.Net MVC and web form but I don't which is better for Sitecore 8.0.

Here is the only related information that I found.
https://www.cmssource.co.uk/blog/2013/october/sitecore-mvc-or-webforms

What technology should i choose- MVC or Web Forms ?

Answer (score 2):

In the *official Sitecore training* we were told to use MVC, and all new Sitecore stuff oriented to **MVC**. Of course you can use webforms, but if you have experience with MVC I would not doubt, use **MVC**.

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

Both are good technologies. But MVC protects you for the future, once Sitecore is upgraded to .net core, WebForms will not be an option, so it will make your upgrade path simpler.